# How do I make a large but unknown number of REST http calls in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, rest, http, orientdb

I have an orientdb database. I want to use nodejs with RESTfull calls to create a large number of records.  I need to get the @rid of each for some later processing.

My psuedo code is:

```
for each record
  write.to.db(record) 
  when the async of write.to.db() finishes
     process based on @rid
carryon()
```

I have landed in serious callback hell from this.  The version that was closest used a tail recursion in the .then function to write the next record to the db.  However, I couldn't carry on with the rest of the processing.

A final constraint is that I am behind a corporate proxy and cannot use any other packages without going through the network administrator, so using the native nodejs packages is essential.

Any suggestions?

Comment: We will need to see how your specific database works for the write in order to know what specific code to suggest.  Chances are it either returns  a promise or takes a completion callback that you would use to know when it was done.

Comment: It requires a POST to a web server.  So I have wrapped the http.on into a promise and resolve the promise in the http.on callback.

Comment: Then, why don't you show that in your question.  You will ALWAYS get better answers if you show more of your own code.  As you can see I've already written an answer assuming a completion callback because you didn't explain what you already had.  I will now go add a method that works better with promises.  Questions with your actual code in them always get better answers than abstract questions with pseudo code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a completion callback, the general design pattern for this type of problem makes use of a local function for doing each write:

```
var records = ....;    // array of records to write
var index = 0;

function writeNext(r) {
    write.to.db(r, function(err) {
       if (err) {
          // error handling
       } else {
          ++index;
          if (index < records.length) {
             writeOne(records[index]);
          }
       }
    });
}

writeNext(records[0]);
```

The key here is that you can't use synchronous iterators like `.forEach()` because they won't iterate one at a time and wait for completion.  Instead, you do your own iteration.

---

If your write function returns a promise, you can use the `.reduce()` pattern that is common for iterating an array.

```
var records = ...;    // some array of records to write

records.reduce(function(p, r) {
    return p.then(function() {
       return write.to.db(r);
    });
}, Promsise.resolve()).then(function() {
   // all done here
}, function(err) {
   // error here
});
```

This solution chains promises together, waiting for each one to resolve before executing the next save.

Comment: @user2302244 - I added a method that assumes your write returns a promise.

Comment: That was just finger trouble.  Sorry.

Comment: I've cluttered up my codebase now.  So I have to do some serious refactoring.  It really shouldn't be this hard  :-(

Comment: Many thanks.  In the end I used the first pattern as I couldn't get my head around the promises that I had created.

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda hard to tell which function would be best for your scenario w/o more detail, but I almost always use `asyncjs` for this kind of thing.

From what you say, one way to do it would be with `async.map`:

```
var recordsToCreate = [...];

function functionThatCallsTheApi(record, cb){
   // do the api call, then call cb(null, rid)
}

async.map(recordsToCreate, functionThatCallsTheApi, function(err, results){
   // here, err will be if anything failed in any function
   // results will be an array of the rids
});
```

You can also check out other ones to enable throttling, which is probablya  good idea.

Comment: :-) Yes.  I used Promise.all([...]) at one stage and the server gave problems.

Comment: The OP said they ***cannot use any other packages*** (which seems a bit odd to me - since that ties the hands of the developer to not be able to use things other people have built).  But, this solution relies on the `async` package.

Comment: He did, but he also said he's using Promises, which are no longer part of Node core libraries, so it seemed more informational than a hard limit.  Especially since he said, "... without going through the network administrator", which implies there's a path to doing it.

Comment: Promises are built into node.js now.  They are part of the ES6 standard.